# Post Images are not showing up whenever I use shortCodes in my posts

Tags: images, shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

This is my issue: Images are not showing up whenever I use shortCodes in my pages.

I am using contact-form shortcode in my website contact page.

And I also have published a header imagen for this page and some other social icons at the bottom of the page (below the contact form)

When I preview the contact page, everything works fine. When I see the live version, the images are not showing up...

If I remove the contact-form short code, the images are shown correctly in live version.

This is the page url:

https://marketingobjetivo.com.br/images-not-showing-up/

Any clue?

Tkssss

Comment: Your image source is showing up as base-64 encoded, and saying it's a gif when it's actually a jpg. I'd contact CF support since this appears to be plugin-specific.

Comment: Thanks WebElaine. 

The mistery is getting bigger....

If you get to the page in Firefox or Internet Explorer, images are shown correctly...

Comment: I finally found out what was causing this issue: the "lazy load images" feature from my website's theme. Once I´ve disabled it, all pictures started to show up again.